# Formatted source view in apache

Tags: svn, apache2

I've setup a svn repository with http access over apache2 and I'm wondering whether there is any apache2 extension or whatever in order to automatically format the source files view while browsing my repo through the internet browser. In other words, something like this:

http://code.google.com/p/stripespotter/source/browse/trunk/src/core/FloatImage.cpp

Is that possible?
Thanks in advance, Luca.

Answer (score 3):

You want **not formatter**, but **syntax highlighter** for repository browser.

[WebSVN](http://www.websvn.info/) with the help from  enscript and GeSHi do it. [WebSVN in action](http://trunk.websvn.info/listing.php?repname=WebSVN)

Comment: @altern - yes, but... I just like WebSVN more for flexibility

Comment: Yes that's just the word I could not remember.... Syntax highlighter... I'll have a look at websvn, thanks!

Comment: I've followed your suggestion and installed websvn + enscript on my ubuntu server... it rocks! Very good and easy to configure! Thank'you very much!